# How to make android dial the # key?

Tags: java, android

My application can dial any number but if I add the # key to the string to call then the number gets truncated just before the #. For example

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "131*4#23"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

The "131*4#23" is just to test the code. I will be using # key in the main application but it is not working. What can I do?

NOTE: I have handled the permission and all the other numbers are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("tel:%s", Uri.encode("131*4#23"))));
```